# dimension of the intersection of subspaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

$K$ is a field, $(a_1,...,a_n)^t,(b_1,...,b_n)^t \in K^n$.

We define the subspaces

$U := \{(x_1, ... x_n) \in K^n|a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n = 0\}$

$V := \{(x_1, ... x_n) \in K^n|b_1x_1+...+b_nx_n = 0\}$

$W := <(a_1,...,a_n)^t,(b_1,...,b_n)^t>$

a) What are the possible dimensions of $W$?

b) Show, that $dim(U \cap V) = n - dim(W)$

My first question is, if someone knows what this to the power of t should mean? I have not seen this notation before, and could find it nowhere...

Therefore, I decided to ignore it provisionally.

I think it is obvious, that $dim(W) \in \{0,1,2\}.$

I proceded with 3 different cases. If $dim(W) = 0$, then $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n = b_1 = ... = b_n = 0$. If follows that $U = V = K^n$, and b) is true.

However, I got stuck with the second case, $dim(W) = 1.$ It follows that at least one $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n$ is not equal to zero. I assumed without loss of generality, that one of the $a_1, ..., a_n$ is nonzero, and furthermore, without loss of generality, that it is $a_n$. Then I wanted to show that $dim(U \cap V) = dim(U) = n-1$. Therefore, I tried to find an isomorphism from $K^{n-1} $ to $U$.

From $a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n = 0$ follows $x_n = \frac{-(a_1x_1+...+a_{n-1}x_{n-1})}{a_n}$. So I defined the isomorphism $h: K^{n-1} \to U, (x_1, ...,x_{n-1}) \mapsto (x_1, ...,x_{n-1}, \frac{-(a_1x_1+...+a_{n-1}x_{n-1})}{a_n})$. I showed that this is an isomorphism and therefore $dim(U) = dim(K^{n-1}) = n-1$.

However, I think this is really ugly, and for the third case, $dim(W) = 2$, it gets even much uglier.

Has someone a different approach to prove this? I feel like there is probably an easier solution...

Answer (score 1):

The $t$ just means transpose, so you are working with column vectors (you are probably supposed to have the $t$ inside your definitions for $U$ and $V$ as well).

Also notice that $U$ and $V$ are each either n- or (n-1)-dimensional. This is because $U$ is the orthogonal complement of $\langle (a_{1},\ldots, a_{n})^{t} \rangle$, or equivalently, the null space of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & \ldots & a_{n} \end{bmatrix}$, which will have either 0 or 1 pivot positions.

Notice that if $(b_{1},\ldots, b_{n})^{t} \in \langle (a_{1},\ldots, a_{n})^{t} \rangle$, then $U \subset V$. Try to show this, it will help.

(You can also notice that $U \cap V$ is the orthogonal complement of $W$).

Comment: Thx for the meaning of t. I know that if $dim(W) = 1$ one is a scalar multiple, and if $dim(W) = 2$ they are independet. But how does that help to determine $dim(U \cap V)$?
I already showed that if one is a scalar multiple of the other, $U = V$. But i still need to show that $dim(U) = n-1$...

Comment: Unfortunately, we did not introduce matrices yet. I already showed that if $(b_{1},\ldots, b_{n})^{t} \in \langle (a_{1},\ldots, a_{n})^{t} \rangle$, then $U = V$. But I still have to show then, that $\dim(U) = n-1$.
I tried to show that $U \cap V$ is the orthogonal complement of $W$, but this is really complicated in the case of $\dim(W) = 2$...

Comment: If $(a_{1},...,a_{n})^{t}$ is not the zero vector, it has at least one nonzero entry; suppose $a_{1}$ is nonzero. Then you have that $(-a_{2}/a_{1} , 1, 0 ,\ldots 0)^{t} \in U$. Can you find more linearly independent solutions to get a basis for $U$?

Comment: $U \cap V$ being the orthogonal complement of $W$ should not be difficult. To be in the intersection of those two spaces, you must be orthogonal to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, which span $W$. Are you having difficulty showing that this is the entire complement?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to show that in the case of $dim(W) = 2$ it is true that $K^n = W + (U \cap V)$...

Comment: In that case $U$ and $V$ are each $n-1$ dimensional. So their intersection is either $(n-1)$-dimensional (if they are equal), or else.... what are the other possibilities? Could they possibly intersect in a space of dimension smaller than $n-2$?